# Absolute positioned animated child div goes out of its parent's boundary, how to fix it?

Tags: html, css

I am animating left position of an absolutely positioned child div within its parent div. The animation though does work but when child div reaches at 50% (`50% {left:100%;}`, it goes out of its parent's boundary.

A.) Why does it happen only for left: 100% and not for 0%?

B.) How to keep child moving within parent - not going out of parent on right hand side?

Here's my code:

```css
#parent {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  margin:100px auto;
  position:relative;
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
#child {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation:animatedPos 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:animatedPos 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:animatedPos 20s linear infinite;
  animation:animatedPos 20s linear infinite;
}

/* The animation code */
@-webkit-keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}

@-o-keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}

@keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: check the duplicate to find a generic solution where you don't need calc or any pixel value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
@keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}
```

to

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
@keyframes animatedPos{
  0%{
    left:0;
  }
  50%{
    left:calc(100% - 100px);
  }
  100%{
    left:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that you have subtracted child div width in 50% selector, but I don't want to use it. I just want a simple and cross-browser compatible solution without this calculation.

Comment: `@keyframes` are IE 10. `calc` is IE 9. I wouldn't even prefix those at this point in time.

Comment: I know StackSlave but I just wanted some other common solution.

Comment: So there is no solution available except subtracting element's width?

Comment: `calc` is common.You can do the math instead, since you know the width of the container, like `50%{ left:400px; }`, but that won't work on a dynamic container *(one that changes size)*.

Comment: That could still work if we are able to find out container's width using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#parent {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  margin:100px auto;
  position:relative;
}

#uncle {
  border:0px solid silver;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:0px auto;
  position:absolute;
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
#child {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation:animatedPos 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:animatedPos 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:animatedPos 20s linear infinite;
  animation:animatedPos 20s linear infinite;
}

/* The animation code */
@-webkit-keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {right:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}

@-o-keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}

@-moz-keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}

@keyframes animatedPos {
  0% {left:0%;}
  50% {left:100%;}
  100% {left:0%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="uncle">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is a workaround adding other Div(uncle) subtracting the animation Width.
The issue is due to the animation using the axis to move taking only one point in consideration, not the animation Width.

Should be cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the width of the child and reduce it from 50%.

Answer (score 0):

You can set 50% as below. 80% is calculated using width given for parent and child 
((500px-100px)/500px)

```
@keyframes animatedPos {
 0% {
  left: 0%;
 }
 50% {
  left: 80%;
 }
 100% {
  left: 0%;
 }
}
```